# How to convert list column to a non-nested list?

Tags: python, pandas

How to convert a column to a non-nested list while the column elements are list?

For example, the column is like

```
column
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2]
```

I want following at last.

```
[1,2,3,1,2]
```

But now with `column.tolist()`, I will get

```
[[1,2,3],[1,2]]
```

EDIT: Thanks for help. My intention is to find the most simple (elegant) and efficient method to do this. Now I use @jezrael method.

```
from itertools import chain
output = list(chain.from_iterable(df[column])
```

The simplest method is provided by @piRSquared, but maybe slower.

```
output = df[column].values.sum()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html):

```
print (np.concatenate(df['column'].values).tolist())
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2]
```

Or:

```
from  itertools import chain
print (list(chain.from_iterable(df['column'])))
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2]
```

Another solution, thanks [juanpa.arrivillaga](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44753778/how-to-convert-list-column-to-a-non-nested-list/44753790#comment76488503_44753790):

```
print ([item for sublist in df['column'] for item in sublist])
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2]
```

**Timings**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column':[[1,2,3], [1,2]]})
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)

In [77]: %timeit (np.concatenate(df['column'].values).tolist())
10 loops, best of 3: 22.7 ms per loop

In [78]: %timeit (list(chain.from_iterable(df['column'])))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.44 ms per loop

In [79]: %timeit ([item for sublist in df['column'] for item in sublist])
100 loops, best of 3: 2.31 ms per loop

In [80]: %timeit df.column.sum()
1 loop, best of 3: 1.34 s per loop
```

Comment: Thanks? But whether there exists any other `method` could do `concat` and `tolist` at one time?

Comment: @danche unlikely. `pandas` wasn't designed to hold `list`s as values.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - Thanks

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thks!

Comment: @danche - in pandas is possible working with another values as scalar, but many function does not work. So best is avoiding it.

Comment: @jezrael Thks for the your advice. :-)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - I prefer your solution long time, but after reading [this timings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/953097/2901002) I start prefer `chain.from_iterable` what is faster.

Comment: @jezrael wow, I use both those approaches frequently, never really preferring one or the other. I figured one would be marginally better, and never imagined that the difference would be by a factor of 2. Good to know.

Answer (score 2):

We concatenate lists with the `+` operator.  Because a pandas series uses its' elements underlying `+` operation when you call `pd.Series.sum`, we can concatenate a whole column, or series, of lists with.

```
df.column.sum()

[1, 2, 3, 1, 2]
```

---

But if you're looking for performance, you can consider `cytoolz.concat`

```
import cytoolz

list(cytoolz.concat(df.column.values.tolist()))

[1, 2, 3, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Hmmm, but it is really slow... plus1

Comment: :-) not trying to be fast on this one.  But it is the simplest.

Comment: exactly, it is simpliest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use append method of list to do this:

```
col = {'col': [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2]]}
last = []
last.extend([i for c in col['col'] for i in c])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that will work is the `list.extend()` method.

`list = []
for row in column:
    list.extend(row)`