# Count and remove elements by conditions from dataframe columns of lists

Tags: python, string, list, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a Pandas df

```
      col_name
1    [16, 4, 30]   
2    [5, 1, 2]   
3    [4, 5, 52, 888]
4    [1, 2, 4]
5    [5, 99, 4, 75, 1, 2]
```

I would like to remove all the elements in the whole column that appears `less than x` times, for example let's take `x = 3`

It means that I would like to have the result looks like:

```
      col_name
1    [4]   
2    [5, 1, 2]   
3    [4, 5]
4    [1, 2, 4]
5    [5, 4, 1, 2]
```

The result df basically removes the number 16, 30, 52, 888, 99 and 75 because it appears less than 3 times in the column.

I tried using `Counter` from `collections` but it didn't work.

Really appreciate if you could give me any hints. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all values less as treshold by [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
from  itertools import chain

a = pd.Series(list(chain.from_iterable(df['col_name']))).value_counts()
a = a.index[a >= 3]
print (a)
Int64Index([4, 5, 2, 1], dtype='int64')

df = df.applymap(lambda x: [v for v in x if v in a])
print (df)
       col_name
1           [4]
2     [5, 1, 2]
3        [4, 5]
4     [1, 2, 4]
5  [5, 4, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Nice, I fleeting thought about prefiltering, neat sir.

Comment: @JohnGalt - Thank you.

Comment: `np.concatenate(df.col_name.tolist())` should be much faster than itertools.

Comment: Maybe in small data, in large not. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44753790/2901002)

Comment: Yes, I was surprised too first time. and `sum` is the worst solution - very slow.

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1**
Somewhat plain vanilla approach

```
s = pd.Series({(i, j): x for (i, r) in df.col_name.items() for j, x in enumerate(r)})

f, u = pd.factorize(s.values)

s[(np.bincount(f) >= 3)[f]].groupby(level=0).apply(list).to_frame('col_name')

       col_name
0           [4]
1     [5, 1, 2]
2        [4, 5]
3     [1, 2, 4]
4  [5, 4, 1, 2]
```

---

**Option 2**
Over the top complicated approach

```
lens = df.col_name.str.len().values
splits = lens.cumsum()[:-1]
values = np.concatenate(df.col_name.values)
f, u = pd.factorize(values)
b = np.bincount(f)
r = np.arange(len(df)).repeat(lens)
m = (b >= 3)[f]
new_splits = splits - np.bincount(r, ~m).astype(int).cumsum()[:-1]
new_values = np.split(values[m], new_splits)
df.assign(col_name=new_values)

       col_name
0           [4]
1     [5, 1, 2]
2        [4, 5]
3     [1, 2, 4]
4  [5, 4, 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

First get `counts` and then `apply` or `applymap` your conditional check for elements.

```
In [2707]: counts = pd.Series([v for x in df.col_name for v in x]).value_counts()

In [2708]: df.col_name.apply(lambda x: [v for v in x if counts[v] >= 3])
Out[2708]:
1             [4]
2       [5, 1, 2]
3          [4, 5]
4       [1, 2, 4]
5    [5, 4, 1, 2]
Name: col_name, dtype: object

In [2709]: df.applymap(lambda x: [v for v in x if counts[v] >= 3])
Out[2709]:
       col_name
1           [4]
2     [5, 1, 2]
3        [4, 5]
4     [1, 2, 4]
5  [5, 4, 1, 2]
```

Details

```
In [2710]: counts
Out[2710]:
4      4
5      3
2      3
1      3
30     1
888    1
52     1
16     1
75     1
99     1
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Counter()` from `collections`:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

limit = 3

df = pd.DataFrame({'col_name': [[16, 4, 30], [5, 1, 2], [4, 5, 52, 888], [1, 2, 4], [5, 99, 4, 75, 1, 2]]})

flat = Counter([y for x in df.col_name for y in x])
desired = [k for k, v in flat.items() if v >= limit]

df['col_name'] = df['col_name'].apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if i in desired])
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46192102/4909087), using `collections.Counter` (but developed independently, with a few optimisations);

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(pd.Series(np.concatenate(df.col_name.tolist())))

def foo(array):
    return [x  for x in array if c[x] >= 3]

df.col_name = df.col_name.apply(foo)
df

       col_name
1           [4]
2     [5, 1, 2]
3        [4, 5]
4     [1, 2, 4]
5  [5, 4, 1, 2]
```