# pandas: aggregate a column of list into one list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, aggregate

I have the following data frame `my_df`:

```
name         numbers
----------------------
A             [4,6]
B             [3,7,1,3]
C             [2,5]
D             [1,2,3]
```

I want to combine all numbers to a new list, so the output should be:

```
 new_numbers
---------------
[4,6,3,7,1,3,2,5,1,2,3]
```

And here is my code:

```
def combine_list(my_lists):
    new_list = []
    for x in my_lists:
        new_list.append(x)

    return new_list

new_df = my_df.agg({'numbers': combine_list})
```

but the `new_df` still looks the same as original:

```
              numbers
----------------------
0             [4,6]
1             [3,7,1,3]
2             [2,5]
3             [1,2,3]
```

What did I do wrong? How do I make `new_df` like:

```
 new_numbers
---------------
[4,6,3,7,1,3,2,5,1,2,3]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need [flatten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python) values and then create new `Dataframe` by constructor:

```
flatten = [item for sublist in df['numbers'] for item in sublist]
```

Or:

```
flatten = np.concatenate(df['numbers'].values).tolist()
```

Or:

```
from  itertools import chain

flatten = list(chain.from_iterable(df['numbers'].values.tolist()))
```

---

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'numbers':[flatten]})
```

---

```
print (df1)
                             numbers
0  [4, 6, 3, 7, 1, 3, 2, 5, 1, 2, 3]
```

**Timings** are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44753790/2901002).

Comment: `functools.reduce(lambda x,y: x+y,l)` should be even faster

Comment: @Wen - I think it depends of sizeof lists, len of df, but [by here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/953097/2901002) the fastest solution is `chain.from_iterable`.

Comment: The first answer is kinda ambiguous to me, is there simplified for statement for the first list comprehension answer?

Comment: @Maeror - it should be simplify, removed `.values.tolist()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use df['numbers'].sum() which returns a combined list to create the new dataframe

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'new_numbers': [df['numbers'].sum()]})

    new_numbers
0   [4, 6, 3, 7, 1, 3, 2, 5, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Unfortunately your solution is [slow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44753790/2901002) :(

Comment: @jezrael, oh I didn't test the timings

Comment: @jezrael, yeah I agree, its surprising slow:(

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

`newdf = pd.DataFrame({'numbers':[[x for i in mydf['numbers'] for x in i]]})`

Answer (score 0):

Check this [pandas groupby and join lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23794082/pandas-groupby-and-join-lists)

What you are looking for is,

my_df = my_df.groupby(['name']).agg(sum)

Comment: Please don't post link only answers to other stackoverflow questions. Instead, vote/flag to close as duplicate, or, if the question is not a duplicate, *tailor the answer to this specific question.*